# How can I find dip direction and a dip of a plane with known normal vectors?

Tags: matlab

I have a question about converting normal vector components of a plane into dip and dip direction.
I have atxt file containing multiple colums and three of than being nx, ny, and nz?
Can you please help me on how to find a dip direction and a dip of a plane.
Note - some of my nz values are negative. Below I am posting a core that i wrote but it is not giving be good values for dip direction.
Thank you for your help

```
load('artificial_slope.txt') %loading data
% defining input values based of input txt file 
nx = data(:,4)
ny = data(:,5)
nz = data(:,6)
% abs vaue of nz component to eliminite minus sign 
nz_abs = abs(nz)
% dip calculation
dip_disc = acos(nz_abs)*(180/pi)
% dip direction calculation (giving wrong results)
dip_dir = (360-atan2(ny,nx) * (180/pi))-90
```

Comment: Hint: the angle of the forward vector w.r.t. the ground should give you that

Comment: I do not know what you mean by that?

Comment: 1) you can compute angles between vectors 2) you can make a vector that points to the direction that the plane is pointing at 3) you can make a vector that is parallel to the ground. 4) combine these 2 ideas  to know the dip